# How do I export a JAR without all the project files (just the src) in Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar

I'm currently using Eclipse as the IDE for a project but I'd like to work with intellij. When I export this project in Eclipse, I get the standard jar (its size is about 80MB). When I try to make an export in Intellij with an artifact, it takes the whole project and creates an "archive" in form of a jar, which has the size of 711MB. How do I get the typical "eclipse export jar" but in Intellij? Is there a method where I can "ignore" the external libraries because they're already in a specific lib folder.